# Could not resoleve uiRouter and child:/id IONIC app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I've a problem with UI-Router in my ionic app, I don't understand how can I go to state child defined by id using `$state.go(state)`

this is my stateProvider:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})
    .state('tab.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'tab-home': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    }
})
    .state('tab.chats', {
    cache: false,
    url: '/chats',
    views: {
        'tab-chats': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
            controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
    }
})
    .state('tab.chat-detail', {
    url: '/chats/:chatId',
    views: {
        'tab-chats': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
            controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
        }
    }
})
```

from the `homeCtrl` I would like to go in chats detail. Firstly I used `$location(tab/chats/123)` but sometimes give me problems..

How can I pass the **id** using `$state.go()`?

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy to find in doc [$state.go](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

```
go(to, params, options)
```

so, we can do it like this:

```
$state.go('tab.chat-detail', {chatId : 123 });
```

small cite from the doc about the second parameter `params`

> A map of the parameters that will be sent to the state, will populate `$stateParams`. Any parameters that are not specified will be inherited from currently defined parameters. This allows, for example, going to a sibling state that shares parameters specified in a parent state. Parameter inheritance only works between common ancestor states, I.e. transitioning to a sibling will get you the parameters for all parents, transitioning to a child will get you all current parameters, etc.

Comment: thanks for your response! i've just tried it but console give me this error:  yes I forgot to say that i try it but console give me this error:                                  
     Error: Could not resolve 'tab.chat-detail.10204833195017020' from state 'tab.home'
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:39965)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:39898)
    at $scope.openPop.$ionicPopup.show.buttons.onTap (homeCtrl.js:92)
    at Scope.IonicModule.factory.$q.all.then.extend.$buttonTapped (ionic.bundle.js:44505)
    at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:20264)
   ...

Comment: I created plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/U34rrbc4HcriGtXJADOE?p=preview *(it is not ionic, but it is **UI-Router** - and it should show how to do that all)*. You will see how to use **href**, **ui-sref** and **$state.go()**. hope it helps